# sql fulltext returning null

Tags: php, sql, joomla, keyword

I'm using the joomla CMS to write to my db and have written a custom front end.

I'm trying to obtain the contents of the 'fulltext' row. I've tried `mysql_fetch_assoc['fulltext']` and `mysql_result($sql, 0, 'fulltext')`. Both return *fulltext*. Here's the query string:

```
SELECT created, modified, title, introtext, 'fulltext', state, urls, created_by
  FROM table_content
 WHERE id='$id'
```

It's probably something really obvious I've missed because fulltext seems to conflict with sql without the quotation marks around it.

Any assistance would as always be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe with `\`fulltext\`` instead of `'fulltext'`

Comment: Thanks gents, knew it would be something daft that i'd overlooked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SQL keywords as field names, with appropriate escaping with backticks. You're using single quotes, which turns the word into a string that contains the word "fulltext".

Try

```
SELECT .... introtext, `fulltext`, state, ...
                       ^--------^--- backticks
```

instead.